# Как сохранить позиции постов при их перемещении, когда обновляется страница?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, firebase, localstorage, task

дорогие друзья!
Делаю тех задание на **vue**, где есть пункт:

[image: тех задание]

Сперва получал эти посты с **localstorage**, где я мог успешно менять посты местами с сохранением позиций. 
Сейчас, Я получаю эти посты уже с **firebase database** и их позицию тоже пытаюсь сохранить в **localstorage**, и при обновлении в первые миллисекунды посты на стоят где надо, но у меня уходит запрос на **firebase**, и посты снова становятся в тот порядок, в котором они прилетели с сервера.

Мне необходимо, чтоб посты прилетали с сервера, их позиции по `id` отправлялись в **localstorage** или как удобнее, но чтоб Я смог перетаскивать их и это все сохранялось так, как описано в тех задании (сверху) локально.

Вот запрос на **firebase** во **vuex**:

```
    async fetchPosts({ commit }) {
      try {
        const response = (await firebase.database().ref(`/posts/`).once("value")).val() || {};

        const posts = Object.keys(response).map((key) => ({
          id: key,
          ...response[key],
        }));

        return posts;
      } catch (e) {
        commit("setError", e);
        throw e;
      }
    }
```

Делал **мутацию** типа:

```
pushPosts(state, posts) {
   state.posts = posts
}
```

Но она постоянно обновляла **state** при новом запросе на **firebase**. А запрос уходит при каждом обновлении.

Прошу помочь решить этот вопрос. Если появятся свои, то задавайте, распишу подробнее! 
Благодарю и хорошего дня!

Comment: написано же, без взяимодействия с сервером. Я так понимаю, имеется ввиду, без использования ajax-запросов. Зачем Вы используете firebase?.

Comment: Я формирую пост на проекте, он отправляется в базу данных **firebase**. Потом я их получаю на главной странице уже с **firebase**. Мне нужна реальная база данных типа. Без взаимодействия с сервером нужно сохранять позиции перемещенных постов. То есть не нужно слать на сервер эту инфу, нужно сохранять в **localstorage** и потом оттуда снова получать все посты с позициями, которые я делал до обновления страницы